# how do I let a iterator operate on a list using the assignment operator

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, assignment-operator, qlist

Dear stackoverflow community, I have question about how to let the qlistiterator operate on a qlist. According to qt's documentation, qlistiterator has a assignment operator "=", like this:

```cpp
QListIterator & QListIterator::operator=(const QList<T> & list)
```

For my code, I have two members in my mainwindow class:

```cpp
QList<int> timepoints;
QListIterator<int> timeIter(QList<int> &list);
```

and in the constructor:

```
timeIter=timepoints;
```

but this line gives an error:

```
invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)
```

Anyone can help explain why?

Answer (score 0):

[QListIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistiterator.html) is being wrongly declared as a member function instead of a member variable.

In your class declaration use:

```
class YourClass {
    QListIterator<int> timeIter;
};
```

The assignment operator allows you to reassign the iterator. It can't be used as you're intending because `QListIterator` doesn't have a default constructor. Therefore to do what you're trying to do, use an initializer:

```
YourClass::YourClass()
    :timeIter{timepoints}
{
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks. For those who might read about this question, I have one comment which might be helpful for understanding the = operator. I just tested it: If there is another QList timepoints2, the timeIter can be reassigned using the = operator: timeIter = timepoints2. And thanks again, replete.